# Unbounded metrics on groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, metric-spaces, geometric-group-theory

If $G$ is an infinite group, is there necessarily an unbounded left-invariant metric on $G$?

Comment: If $G$ is countable, then tehre exists even a proper invariant metric, as can be seen here: http://www.math.uni-bielefeld.de/~amanouss/papers/jlms1.pdf

Comment: Do you mean $\textit{countable}$ group? Otherwise just take the uncountable product of a discrete group. The result is reasonably nice (ie it's a compact topological group). However, the underlying space is not metrizable. 

Comment: @Owen Sizemore: there is no compatibility with any given topology asked in the question.

Comment: No compatibility? Then the 0-1 metrics would be an answer.

Comment: @Wlodzimierz: how do you prove that the 0-1 metric is unbounded? :)

Comment: @Yves: Let me try. Hm, it seems harder than the millennium problems.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The answer is no. See Thm 1.2 of http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~rosendal/PapersWebsite/Property(OB)10.pdf. There is a property discussed in the intro of this paper which is equivalent to all left invariant metrics are bounded. It is known that certain large permutation groups have this property.

Comment: This is actually originally due to Bergman (Bull London Math Soc) http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0401304, Rosendal considers the version for a group endowed with a topology.

Comment: Thanks Yves. I realized only the intro talks about this but I didn't have a link to Bergman's paper. 

Comment: Very interesting answers. Thank you.